# Executing a .ps1 file from a .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a .bat file that that executes a list of things with no issues. It get to the powershell execute line: 
    PowerShell.exe "Y:\Data\FS01\NoTouch_Deploy.ps1"

I get the following error: 
    WARNING: Failed to load the 'SQLAS' extension: An exception in SMO While trying to manage a service. --> Failed to retrieve data for this request. --> Invalid class

When I run the same script through the GUI, it runs with no issues. I have also tried and running a simple Powershell script in the same spot (the test one just throws up a Windows Message box, to let me know it is opening and executing) this works as well.  but once I add in the regular .ps1 and run it from a .bat file I get this error.  The script is included below.  Quick summary of the script: It sets a few variables creates 2 functions (BCP, and a logwrite for error trapping) renames some tables and fires SQL Stored Procedure.  then executes the BCP function to move data from server to server, then executes one more Procedure.

```
cls

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
## TEST MSGBOX## [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("We are proceeding with next step." , "Status") 
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data")
Add-PsSnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-PsSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Import-Module SQLPs -DisableNameChecking -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Import-Module SQLAS    -DisableNameChecking -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-Location 'C:\'
# Set Variables (Make table driven for final tool creation)
$SourceServer = "DevServ"
$SourceDB = "DevDB"
$SourceObject = "DevTable"
$TargServer = "ProdServ"
$TargDB = "ProdDB"
$TargObject = "ProdTable" 
$ContainerDB =  'MainDB'

################################################################################################################
##                                      Begin Function LogWrite                                              ##
##################################################################################################### ###########
Function LogWrite ()
    {
        Param
            (

                [string]$LogStr,
                [string]$Table,
                [string]$Server,
                [string]$DataBase
            )

        Trap{continue} 
        #$DateTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y:%MM:%D:%H:%M:%S"

        $LogInsQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Deploy_LOG ([TableName], [LOGTEXT],[DateStamp]) VALUES ('" + $Table + "', '" + $LogStr + "',getdate())"
         Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SServer -Database $SDB -Query $LogInsQuery

    }
################################################################################################################
##                                      Begin Function BCP
################################################################################################################


Function BCP ()
    {
        Param
            (
                [string]$SourceServer,
                [string]$SourceDB,
                [string]$SourceObject,
                [string]$TargServer,
                [string]$TargDB,
                [string]$TargObject
            )
        $NewServer

        Try
            {
                $SourceCon = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $SourceCon.ConnectionString = "Data     Source=$SourceServer;DataBase=$SourceDB;Integrated Security=True"

                Logwrite  "$TargObject -- Beginning BCP transfer process" $SourceObject

                $TargCon = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $TargCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$TargServer;DataBase=$TargDB;Integrated Security=True"
                $TargCon.open()

                #[long]$StartCount = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SourceServer -Query "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Ct' FROM $TargDB.dbo.$TargObject")[0]

                $bcp = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($TargCon.ConnectionString, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity)

                $FieldsServer = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $TargServer
                $DevServer = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" $SourceServer

                $SelectString = 'SELECT '
                $DevServer.Databases[$TargDB].Tables | ?{$_.name -eq $TargObject} | %{$_.Columns | %{$SelectString += "[$($_.name)],"}}
                $SelectString = $SelectString.Substring(0, ($SelectString.Length - 1)) # Remove the trailing comma
                $SelectString += " FROM dbo.$SourceObject"

                $SourceCon.open()
                $SqlCmd = New-Object "Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" -ArgumentList $SelectString, $SourceCon
                [Data.IDataReader]$DataReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

                $bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
                $bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.$TargObject"
                $bcp.WriteToServer($DataReader)

                $SqlCmd = $null
                $DataReader = $null                                     
                $SourceCon.Close()
                $bcp.Close()

                $TargCon.Close()

                LogWrite  "$TargObject -- Transfer complete" $SourceObject;
             }
        Catch
            {
                LogWrite "ERROR in BCP Subroutine -- $_" $SourceObject;
            }

    }

################################################################################################################
##                                      Begin main code section end of functions    
################################################################################################################

Try
             {

    $SqlQuery = "SP_Rename 'TableName','TableName_Deploy'"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SServer -Database $SDB -Query $SqlQuery
    $SqlQuery =""

# runs the Sproc on the FLD server to make sure that the _Deploy table exists, is empty and is indexed. 
    $DeployTableSproc = "EXECUTE  [dbo].[SP_NoTouch_Staging_Build]"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $TargServer -Database $ContainerDB -Query $DeployTableSproc

# Runs the BCP process to copy the records to the Feild into the new prepared table. 
BCP $SServer $SDB $SourceObject $TargServer $TargDB $TargObject


    $SqlQuery = "EXECUTE [MainDB].[dbo].[Notify_NoTouch] @EmailType =  6"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SServer -Database $SDB -Query $SqlQuery
    $SqlQuery =""


LogWrite  "No touch table transfer complete Table renamed and indexed" $SourceObject;

            }
        Catch
            {
                LogWrite "ERROR in Transfer process" $SourceObject;
            }
```

I tried to add 
    #Import-Module SQLAS    -DisableNameChecking -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
It did not help.  any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Adding `#Import-Module` did nothing because `#` indicates that everything that follows is a comment - it'll never be executed. But under v3 and newer, that's not important because modules are automatically imported if needed.

Comment: I commented it out after I ran it and it did nothing.  Sorry I left it commented when I pasted it here. I think I am still on V2

Comment: How is the batch file being run? Are you running it manually or is it a scheduled task possibly running under a different account? How are you running the script manually outside of the batch file, via the ISE or the console? Do you auto-load things in your ISE profile that are not loaded for the console?

Comment: For testing this I am simply clicking on a .bat file to execute. It will eventually be run by a task scheduler, but using my profile. Outside the .bat file I am using powerGUI to run the .ps1 script. I have not tried it via the console, but I will do it now. 
I am not sure what you mean by Auto-Load things in my ISE profile..

Comment: Load up PowerShell and type in `notepad $profile` and hit enter. See if things are listed there. You should do the same in both the console and PowerGUI (I assume it uses the same function to map it's profile for consistency's sake). That runs anytime you launch PowerShell. I know my ISE profile sets the consolepanelbackgroundcolor to black, changes the current folder, and loads 3 modules anytime I launch it.

Comment: Nothing comes up when I run this. Just a blank notepad, and system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 2):

Since you ultimately want to run this script via task scheduler, I would go ahead and create the task on the server you want it on.  In the Actions tab, just set the following criteria:

**Program/script field**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**Add Arguments field:**

```
-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -nologo -command "&{\\path\to\your\files\FileName.ps1 -Silent:$true}"
```

If you want to test this with a batch file, just have some code like this:

```
schtasks /RUN /s "ServerName" /TN "Scheduled Tasks Named" | Out-String
```